# cy.click('div.wrapper') or cy.check('input[type=checkbox]', { force: true })?

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, cypress

Let's say there is some hidden checkbox wrapped with a styled `div` element:

```html
<div class="wrapper beautiful-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" style="display: none">
</div>
```

In Cypress I want to test when user clicks on this element to choose this option. Which `cy` event is more suitable from the perspective of real user interaction:

- `cy.click('div.wrapper')` - test user click event on wrapper element
- `cy.check('input[type=checkbox]', { force: true })` - test `check` event on the actual hidden checkbox using `force: true` option